# Naming my inline pdf

Tags: java, pdf, servlets

I am creating a pdf in a java servlet, and when my created pdf opens it incorrectly names that pdf after my servlet. Here is my code:

```
     response.setHeader(contentDisposition, "inline; filename=TemporaryVerification.pdf");

     try {

         reader = new PdfReader(CreateStuVerification.class.getResource("/resource/" +     tempFile));
         stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, response.getOutputStream());
```

So I want my pdf to be named "TemporaryVerification.pdf", but it is name "CreateStuVerification.pdf"(which is the name of my servlet).  Does anyone know why this is, and possibly how to correct it?

EDIT:  I do have to keep it as an inline pdf.  Though when I tried it as an attachment, it was correctly named.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is specific to the IE browser. It uses the last part of the URI path as default name of the downloaded resource. The more sane browsers properly use the `filename` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` header for this.

You'd better remap your servlet on a path pattern such as `/pdf/*` and then append the desired filename straight into the URL which is supposed to return the PDF like so

```html
<a href="pdf/TemporaryVerification.pdf">
```

You can if necessary get the filename part in the servlet as follows:

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1); // TemporaryVerification.pdf
// ...
```